# Cannot connect on psql specifying connection string postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

On my Ubuntu machine, I have installed postgres 15. I created a new superuser called "test" (with password "test"). Then, I created a database called "test" as well and granted all privileges to the user test.
Here the sequence of steps I made:

```
# Create a new user on Ubuntu
sudo adduser test

# Create the user test on postgres
sudo -u postgres psql postgres;
CREATE USER test SUPERUSER;
ALTER USER test WITH PASSWORD 'test';
exit;

# Login with test to create the DB and being the owner of the DB
sudo -u test psql postgres;
CREATE DATABASE test;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE test TO test;
exit;
```

From psql, when I try the following I can successfully connect:

```
psql -d test -U test
```

However, If I try:

```
psql postgresql://test:test@localhost:5432/test
```

I get: *psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test"*

I browsed on the internet, but without any success. This is the relevant part of mu pg_hba.conf file.
[image]

Any help?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us, by copying and pasting properly formatted text, not images, how exactly you "created a new superuser called "test" (with password "test") [and] a database called "test" as well and granted all privileges"...

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid WHERE rolname = 'test';`? The start of the result string will show us how your password is hashed. You can simply remove the `localhost` from the URL, and the connection should work again.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the start of the result is "SCRAM-SHA-256". So the command would be "postgresql://test:test@:5432/test"?

Comment: The command would be `psql postgresql://test:test@:5432/test` to get a socket connection. Did you reload PostgreSQL to make sure the config file is actually used? What exactly is the error message in the PostgreSQL log?

Comment: With that command I get "psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?". Yes, I did "sudo service postgresql restart" many times. On the log at "/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-15-main.log" this error seems not to be logged.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different auth methods `md5` for local(socket) and `scram-sha-256` for host(ip). This `psql -d test -U test` is using socket and `md5`, the other is using `host` and `scram-sha-256`. Your passwords are set up as `md5`. The solution is change the `scram-sha-256` to `md5` and reload pg_hba.conf

Per docs [Password auth](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html):

> To ease transition from the md5 method to the newer SCRAM method, if md5 is specified as a method in pg_hba.conf but the user's password on the server is encrypted for SCRAM (see below), then SCRAM-based authentication will automatically be chosen instead.

Then you can change your passwords to `scram-sha-256` over time.

Comment: I changed the 4 lines beginning with "host" to md5 in the pg_hba.conf file, got a restart with "sudo service postgresql restart", but still not working. The error remains the same. Did I get wrong something?

Comment: 1) You sure you changed the correct file? 2) Does `psql -d test -U test` still work? 3) As a superuser do `select * from pg_shadow ;`  to check whether the prefix for the passwords are `md5` or `SCRAM-SHA-256`.

Comment: 1) Yes, I changed it at "/etc/postgresql/15/main/pg_hba.conf". 2) Yes, it still works 3) I see the prefix SCRAM-SHA-256 for the passwords. Not an expert, but maybe because the user test was created before changing the pg_hba.conf file?